# More efficient GUI design for JTextArea project

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently working on enhancing a project at work which requires me to create 6 different GUI's. I should start by saying I am extremely bad at GUI design. I have tried to learn Grid Bag but really found it difficult.

In this GUI I am using BorderLayout and Flow Layout and it works fine. I am able to create the GUI's and accomplish the objective but I can't help feeling like this method is not professional and is going to have a lot of unnecessary code if my other GUI's end up having a lot more JTextFields and JLabels (which some will).

I would like to know if there are any layouts that can reduce the amount of panels I have here. I have explored Grid layouts but am concerned about all cells being the same size. If someone can help by letting me know, from their experience, the best layout for this project and maybe show me how to use it I would appreciate it. I've tried doing layout tutorials like GridBag layout but have problems actually implementing it on my own projects.

Main Class

```
package mainClasses;

import gui.AllGUI;

public class TesterClass 

{

    public static void main(String args[])

    {

        AllGUI guiALL = new AllGUI();
        guiALL.createAllGUI();



    }

}
```

GUI

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class AllGUI 

{

    public void createAllGUI(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("All File Types Selection");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panelOne = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panelLine1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel panelLine2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel panelLine3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel panelLine4 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel panelLine5 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        JButton confirmButton = new JButton("Confirm");

        JLabel groupMessageIdTitle = new JLabel("Group Message Id:");
        JLabel isoDateTimeTitle = new JLabel("ISO Creation Date/Time:");
        JLabel notificationIdTitle = new JLabel("Notification Id:");
        JLabel notificationAcctIdTitle = new JLabel("Notification Account Id:");
        JLabel numberOfEntriesTitle = new JLabel("Number of Entries:");
        JLabel sumOfAmountsTitle = new JLabel("Sum of Amounts:");
        JLabel fileTypeTitle = new JLabel("Camt54 File Type:");

        JTextField groupMessageIdText = new JTextField("",10);
        JTextField isoDateTimeText = new JTextField("",10);
        JTextField notificationIdText = new JTextField("",10);
        JTextField notificationAcctIdText = new JTextField("",10);
        JTextField numberOfEntriesText = new JTextField("",10);
        JTextField sumOfAmountsText = new JTextField("",10);

        String[] fileTypes = {"OTC-R Message", "Home-Banking", "Cleared Checks"};

        JComboBox fileTypesComboBox = new JComboBox(fileTypes);

        panelLine1.add(groupMessageIdTitle);
        panelLine1.add(groupMessageIdText);
        panelLine1.add(isoDateTimeTitle);
        panelLine1.add(isoDateTimeText);
        panelLine2.add(notificationIdTitle);
        panelLine2.add(notificationIdText);
        panelLine2.add(notificationAcctIdTitle);
        panelLine2.add(notificationAcctIdText);
        panelLine3.add(numberOfEntriesTitle);
        panelLine3.add(numberOfEntriesText);
        panelLine3.add(sumOfAmountsTitle);
        panelLine3.add(sumOfAmountsText);
        panelLine4.add(fileTypeTitle);
        panelLine4.add(fileTypesComboBox);
        panelLine5.add(confirmButton);

        panelOne.add(panelLine1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panelOne.add(panelLine2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelOne.add(panelLine3,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        mainPanel.add(panelOne,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(panelLine4,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(panelLine5,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.setSize(630,210);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

Comment: This is opinion-based, which is off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: I don't see how this is considered totally opinion based. Good code writing is well documented and known. I am asking for someone with more experience on good code writing to let me know if there is a better way to do this - I'm asking for help based on experience not only opinions.

Comment: You're asking if the code design looks professional. What people may define as "professional" is opinion based. Sounds like you want people to give you tips on how to improve your code. You should go to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for that. StackOverflow is for when you have a *specific* concern

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask - Says that subjective opinions are allowed as long as there is also substance involved. I also asked for a practical solution to my programming problem, that is, how to reduce the amount of code by utilizing a layout scheme. I have trouble with layouts so someone who has experience may be able to help me.

Comment: You are requesting a review, not specifying a specific problem (code not looking professional is not a specific problem, it's a potential group of unspecified problems). The problem here is less specific than the one [asked in this question that I answered](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/123480/swing-gui-in-java), and even that question was migrated to CodeReview. You don't have an actual problem (the code works), and you don't have a specific design that you are asking about, so unless you were more specific about the issue, this would be considered a review request.

Comment: There's nothing un-professional about using nested layouts in a GUI.  However, if you have a series of JLabel / JTextfield pairs, the GridBagLayout alignes the labels and fields in columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is an opinion, but I think this GUI looks more professional.

[image: All File Types]

The labels and text fields are aligned in columns.  I used the GridBagLayout to create the form portion of the GUI.

Here's the code.  I grouped the JFrame code, the JPanel code, and the Swing components within the JPanel together so the code is easier to understand.

I put the main method with this code so I'd only have one file to paste.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AllGUI {

    private static final Insets normalInsets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new AllGUI().createAllGUI();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }

    public void createAllGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("All File Types Selection");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel formPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        int gridy = 0;

        JLabel groupMessageIdTitle = new JLabel("Group Message Id:");
        addComponent(formPanel, groupMessageIdTitle, 0, gridy, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JTextField groupMessageIdText = new JTextField("", 10);
        addComponent(formPanel, groupMessageIdText, 1, gridy, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel isoDateTimeTitle = new JLabel("ISO Creation Date/Time:");
        addComponent(formPanel, isoDateTimeTitle, 2, gridy, 1, 1, normalInsets,
                GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JTextField isoDateTimeText = new JTextField("", 10);
        addComponent(formPanel, isoDateTimeText, 3, gridy++, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel notificationIdTitle = new JLabel("Notification Id:");
        addComponent(formPanel, notificationIdTitle, 0, gridy, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JTextField notificationIdText = new JTextField("", 10);
        addComponent(formPanel, notificationIdText, 1, gridy, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel notificationAcctIdTitle = new JLabel("Notification Account Id:");
        addComponent(formPanel, notificationAcctIdTitle, 2, gridy, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JTextField notificationAcctIdText = new JTextField("", 10);
        addComponent(formPanel, notificationAcctIdText, 3, gridy++, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel numberOfEntriesTitle = new JLabel("Number of Entries:");
        addComponent(formPanel, numberOfEntriesTitle, 0, gridy, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JTextField numberOfEntriesText = new JTextField("", 10);
        addComponent(formPanel, numberOfEntriesText, 1, gridy, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel sumOfAmountsTitle = new JLabel("Sum of Amounts:");
        addComponent(formPanel, sumOfAmountsTitle, 2, gridy, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JTextField sumOfAmountsText = new JTextField("", 10);
        addComponent(formPanel, sumOfAmountsText, 3, gridy++, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JLabel fileTypeTitle = new JLabel("Camt54 File Type:");
        addComponent(formPanel, fileTypeTitle, 0, gridy, 1, 1, normalInsets,
                GridBagConstraints.LINE_START, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        String[] fileTypes = { "OTC-R Message", "Home-Banking",
                "Cleared Checks" };
        JComboBox<String> fileTypesComboBox = new JComboBox<>(fileTypes);
        addComponent(formPanel, fileTypesComboBox, 1, gridy, 1, 1,
                normalInsets, GridBagConstraints.LINE_START,
                GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL);

        JPanel confirmPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton confirmButton = new JButton("Confirm");
        confirmPanel.add(confirmButton);

        mainPanel.add(formPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(confirmPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        return mainPanel;
    }

    private void addComponent(Container container, Component component,
            int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, Insets insets,
            int anchor, int fill) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(gridx, gridy,
                gridwidth, gridheight, 0.0D, 0.0D, anchor, fill, insets, 0, 0);
        container.add(component, gbc);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much. I have tried using GridBag before but didn't have much luck, I had problems putting the tutorial concepts into an actual work project. I think with this I can expand on it and make it work for me. This looks much better and I think is the best way to go. I appreciate your help very much!